# Verb that means to get rid of obstacle (person or thing) or to make it disappear as if by magic (such as by staring at it or thinking about it)

Tags: word-request

I saw an example for this verb on Google Dictionary but forgot the word. As I best recall, its meaning is "to get rid of obstacle (person or thing) or to make it disappear **as if by magic** (such as **by staring at it or by thinking about it**)". I'm not totally sure that it's a figure of speech that stems from another word or its a standalone entry but as I read the example it's pretty straightforward to understand its meaning.

For its length, unless my memory betrays me, it's a single-word. Otherwise, the verb phrase should be at most two words long (though I bet my memory can be trusted on this part).

The word has surfaced in my head many times and tortured me for forgetting it. Can you please help!

Comment: ***dismiss, send packing, obviate, banish, repudiate, eliminate, exterminate,...***

Comment: I have seen the phrasal verb **wish (something) away** defined as "to cause something to disappear merely by desiring it to be gone"

Comment: "Wish away" is very very close, yet I don't think it's the one I saw. But I guess sometimes in life I need to content myself with what's available.

Comment: @TimR maybe it's the one I saw. It's the exact example on Google Dictionary I've seen that I don't see it now anymore and my memory pains me just because of that : (

Answer (score 2):

"Disappear", as a transitive verb might fit:
[M-W disappear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disappear)

transitive verb
: to cause (someone or something) to disappear:

a: to abduct and kill or imprison (someone, such as a political dissident) while withholding information about the person's fate

**b: to cause (something) to pass out of existence, possession, or view**

(See definition for usage examples.)

Comment: I know this word but it's not the one I'm looking. I've added some details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a vague description, but '[**dispel**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dispel)' might work, specifically in the sense of:

> to cause to vanish; alleviate

The example "*to dispel her fears*" is given. Other examples on the linked page show that it is regularly used to express that something unwanted is being removed.

Since you're asking for a word meaning "*to make disappear **as if by magic***", 'dispel' is especially apt: while not etymologically related, it carries an association with the word 'spell', a magic word (and thus "de-spell", or "dis-spell", in the sense of undoing a spell).

Comment: First of all, 'dispel' might sound like the word 'spell' but it has nothing at all to do with magic. It is etymologically similar to '*expel*' or '*impel*', neither of which even have an 's' in them. But crucially one dispels something unreal with logic and reason - for example, *dispel a myth*. It's the very opposite of making something real disappear with magic.

Comment: @Astralbee I know: it's by association, as pointed out clearly. And it's not clear from the OP's description what kind of obstacle is being removed—a "thing" can be an abstraction, something unreal, as well. "Disappear" (as well as "vanish") has less of a connection to "magic", hence my answer.

Comment: @Astralbee Despite my rebuttal, it is still not worth removing the downvote (or at least giving a refuting remark, also as an act of acknowledgment)? That comes across as quite unfriendly, especially given that you answered the question at the same time (with an answer that is somewhat similarly based on a condition).

Answer (score 1):

**Magic (away)** is most probably the word that I was looking for. Some other examples of (the verb) "magic":

- I wish I could magic us away to a warm beach.
- "He must have been magicked out of the car at the precise second it exploded"

I can't say for sure since I haven't been able to retrieve the example sentence (for the wanted word) from Google Dictionary that best matches what's in my blurry memory for the word.

Answer (score 0):

'*Vanish*' is an intransitive verb in the English dictionary - that is one that does not hold an object. In other words, someone or something can vanish, but it's not an action one does to something else.

However, in fiction, 'vanish' *is* used transitively. For example, in the Harry Potter books the 'vanishing spell' is said to "*vanish both animate and inanimate objects "into non-being*". So, you could use that word creatively, but if you wanted to obey the usual rules of grammar you could say something like you "*caused [x] to vanish*".

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vanish) gives the transitive version of *vanish* (which was one of the words I immediately thought of).